# When to Breakup a Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller that handles about 6 or 7 URLs, each with a POST and GET.  Most are related functions (issue refund, change price, etc).

Are there any guidelines or best practices for breaking up a controller by URL or function?

Part of me wants to have a separate controller for each GET/POST pair.  If there is any duplicated code, I'd create a utility class.

I am curious to know how others handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually break it up by the URLs. But I usually have one GET and then multiple POST requests (1). However, if there are only GET/POST pairs inside some functionality, I put them in a 'parent' controller (2).

(1) For example for the "Promotion" functionality (that has different kinds of promotions handled) I would make PromotionController as the main controller for that functionality and than make controllers for every kind of the promotion.

(2) For example for the "Registration" functionality, which has few steps and in every step just the GET/POST pair, I would put it all in the one controller.